# Global name 'dataobjects' is not defined in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mergeshapes

I have this small problem with QGIS 2.18.4 Las Palmas. I just downloaded it and tried to merge vector layers, but i've got error: "global name 'dataobjects' is not defined". 
I didn't change anything that in my opinion could cause this problem. Although I wanted to use lastools via QGIS, so I connected it in previous version (as far as I remember it was QGIS 2.14) and due to some errors I had to remove some folder paths to Grass, but everything worked just fine, so it's probably not the cause.
I tried to merge shapes by the plugin, but it didn't work either.
Any ideas how i can fix this?

Comment: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/16292 looks like a 2.18.4 bug. Works fine in 2.14.12. Looks like a regression, i remind me it was working in 2.18.3

Comment: QGIS 2.18.4 Las Palmas 64 bits : Same problem: "Merge vector layers global name 'dataobjects' is not defined". Reinstalling long term release: 2.14.12-Essen ->Problem solved

Comment: Will be fixed in 2.18.5

Comment: I've changed Merge.py file (following the code from hub.qgis.org/issues/16292) and now it works just fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I'm running 2.18.4 as well and just found this thread searching for a fix. I tried using the MMQGIS plugin's 'Merge Layers' function to successfully combine 50+ shapefiles into one file -- worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the same issue and figured out a work around.

Toggle the two layers 'on' for editing. Select all of the features you want to merge from layer A ,  copy. Highlight layer B in the layers panel, paste. Toggle off editing and save changes.

Probably make a copy of both files before hand also.

I have no idea why we're getting the error "global name 'dataobjects' is not defined", but this got me through the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running, what seems like, an endless amount of troubleshooting for this problem and have decided to uninstall both LTR 2.14.12 and 2.18.4.  Merge worked initially in 2.14.12, but I was not able to reload my initial data to test for consistency.  In 2.18.4 I was able to load my data with no problems but the merge function was receiving the "global name 'dataobjects' is not defined" error.  From what I understand, 2.18.5 is releasing tomorrow (3/24/2017) and this bug will be fixed. I am currently reinstalling 2.14.12 to test for consistency once more.  Also, @JuliaStrzyż and @Chansen, the SAGA merge vector layers seemed to work as well, if not, more flawlessly than MMQGIS.  Just another option to add to your lists of work-arounds.